# GeoDjango admin: how to use a WMS background other than the default OSM or VMAP0

Tags: wms, geodjango

The standard GeoDjango admin has a basic VMAP0 background. `OsmGeoAdmin` adds an OSM background.

How do I replace the background map with another WMS?

In the [source code of the admin OpenLayers template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/templates/gis/admin/openlayers.js#L115) there are `{{ wms_url }}` and `{{ wms_name }}` variables but I cannot find where these can be specified to customize it.

Or should I just completely override the default admin template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to read **[Improving the Admin](http://blog.adamfast.com/2011/11/improving-the-admin/)** from http://blog.adamfast.com/

```
{% extends "gis/admin/openlayers.js" %}

{% block extra_layers %}
    topo_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "USA Topo", "http://terraservice.net/ogcmap.ashx", {layers: 'DRG'} );
    {{ module }}.map.addLayer(topo_layer);
    nexrad_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "NEXRAD", "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi?", {layers:"nexrad-n0r",transparent:"true",format:'image/png'} );
    {{ module }}.map.addLayer(nexrad_layer);
{% endblock extra_layers %}
```

i hope it helps you...